# Is it true that if the length of any vector under a transformation and its adjoint is the same the transformation is normal?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I've been trying to check that if $Ax$ and $A^*x$ have the same length for all vectors $x$ in a complex inner product space, then $A$ is normal. Using the property of the adjoint, I calculated $||Ax||^2=<Ax,Ax>=<A^*Ax,x>$ and $||A^*x||^2=<A^*x,A^*x>=<AA^*x,x>$. However, I can't figure out if this implies $A^*A=AA^*$. Is the statement even true and if so, what simple observation am I missing after this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a theorem that says:  Let $T$ be a linear operator in complex vector space $V$.  If $\langle v, Tv \rangle=0$ for all $v\in V$ then $T=0$.

To apply this theorem you could reason as follows:
$$||Ax||^2 = ||A^*x||^2 \\
\langle Ax,Ax\rangle = \langle A^*x,A^*x \rangle \\
\langle x,A^*Ax\rangle = \langle x,AA^*x \rangle \\
\langle x,A^*Ax\rangle - \langle x,AA^*x \rangle =0\\
\langle x,A^*Ax-AA^*x \rangle =0 \\
\langle x,(A^*A-AA^*)x \rangle =0 \\
A^*A-AA^*=0 \\
A^*A=AA^*$$

Proof of the theorem is given in the course notes of MIT 8.05, Quantum Physics II.  There is a chapter on Linear Algebra in notes for the Fall 2013 semester.  In that chapter, the theorem is given as Equation 7.24.  This link to [MIT 8.05 course notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-05-quantum-physics-ii-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT8_05F13_Chap_03.pdf) may not be persistent.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the theorem, it was what I was looking for.

Comment: Note: This theorem does not hold in the real inner product space. A simple counter-example would be- choose R2 for V, and define T(x,y) = (-y,x). Then <T(v)|v> is 0 (standard inner product), though T!=0 operator.